# Crysis 2 BUG after defeating 1st Pinger

Tags: crysis-2

In the game [Crysis 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crysis_2), after the destroying the first Pinger, there is a glitch.

I'm at the part when you encounter the first pinger. After I defeat it the wall falls down and 2 jeeps dive out of it. Then some dude gets out the car and my mission is to regroup at him. If I go to him nothing happens, after like 20 min he starts to walk arround abit but nothing more.

I read that some other people have the same problem. Is there gonna be a fix for this? I already reïnstalled the game. 
I bought via steam.

Comment: Copy-paste from EA's official forum (http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/5523027.page). After reading there (as I am sure you did), I don't think there's an official solution. Some people mentioned that restarting the Chapter worked for them.

Comment: thats was me there